# Can't connect to my webserver from external source

Tags: webserver, portforwarding

I am having problems connecting to my website from a source outside my local network. I had another server before running the same site. The only difference is the old one was FreeBSD and now I'm trying it on Linux.

Here is my setup: I'm using Apache2. The server is behind a Netgear router. I'm using a Freedns host name. I have ddclient updating my ip.

Here is what happens: I can look at my site from the server in Chrome or my phone connected to the local wifi. It works using either the host name or ip address. It does not load from my cell phone or from my desktop using a proxy for either the host name or the ip address (the external one from googling my ip and from the router's wan info page). When I try the proxy with the host name I get "conection timed out" error, and when I try the ip address I get "couldn't connect to host error".

Here is what I've tried: I enabled port forwarding to the server from and to port 80 to my lan ip address. I disabled the firewall on the server. I double checked that the host name is directed to the right ip address. I ensured that the ip address does indeed point to my router. I've watched wireshark on my server while trying to connect and don't see any incoming requests when I try to load it from my phone.

It seems like maybe my port forwarding isn't working, but on my router it says that that port forwarding rule is active.

I'm out of ideas as to why what else could be going wrong.